# Cauchy-Riemann Equations Written as Complex Conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis

Apparently, it can be shown that the Cauchy-Riemann equations can be written simply as, $df/dz^*=0$. I do not understand how it does not immediately follow from this that $df/dz=0$.

When we proved the relations originally, we used
$$\frac{df}{dz} = \frac{\delta u+i\delta v}{\delta x+i\delta y}$$
Taking both the limits $\delta x\to0$ and $\delta y \to 0$, and requiring they be equal for the derivative to be defined.

Doing the same thing for $df/dz^*$, we get exactly the same thing for $\delta x\to 0$. Since this has to be zero, haven't we also shown that $df/dz=0$ if $df/dz^*$ is defined? Or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: After thinking about it more over the night; All I can get out of this is that if $df/dz^*$ is defined and non-zero, then $df/dz$ cannot be defined. However, I don't see how any of this guarantees that the derivative $df/dz$ exists, like the original C-R relations do. In other words, if $df/dz^*$ is undefined, that tells us nothing about $df/dz$, which could either be defined or undefined, right?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is defined as 
$$
f'(z) = \lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{f(z+\Delta z) - f(z)}{\Delta z}.
$$
Let $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$.
The limit must be the same no matter how we set up $\Delta z\to 0$. Suppose we choose only real values for $\Delta z$. The imaginary part is a constant so the derivative is with respect to $x$.
$$
f'(z) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
$$
Now if we hold the reals constant, we have
$$
f'(z) = -i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
$$
since we would have had
$$
f'(z) = \lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{f(z+i\Delta z) - f(z)}{i\Delta z}.
$$
Therefore, $f_x = -if_y$ or
$$
u_x = v_y\qquad\text{and}\qquad u_y = -v_x
$$
which are the Cauchy Riemann equations. Let $f(x,y)$ be a complex functions of real variables $x,y$. Let $z=x+iy$ and $\bar{z}=x-iy$ so 
$$
x=(z+\bar{z})/2\qquad\text{and}\qquad y = -i(z-\bar{z})/2.
$$
Then
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 1/2\Bigl[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigr]\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar{z}} = 1/2\Bigl[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigr]
$$
Recall that $f_x = -if_y$ so 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar{z}} = 1/2\Bigl[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigr] = 1/2\Bigl[-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigr] = 0.
$$
Since $f_x = -if_y$,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 1/2\Bigl[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigr] = 1/2\Bigl[-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigr] = -i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}.
$$

Comment: How do you define $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$?

Comment: @Laters what do you mean? It is in the photocopy of Alhfors you posted. Then I used the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ which I just called $f_x=-if_y$.

Comment: You say "then ..." but as Ahlfors points out, you cannot really do this, you must define $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ by these equations. if you just say "then..." you do not indicate that you define the LHS by the RHS

Comment: @Laters would you feel more comfortable with "then we could write the derivatives as..."?

Comment: @dustin sir,  what if for some function $\frac{∂f}{∂x}(z_0)$ and $\frac{∂f}{∂y}(z_0)$ does not exists? then what to say? Cauchy Riemann equations are satisfied or Not? (I have function defined as $\frac{\bar{z}^{2}}{z^2}$ when $z≠0$ and $0$ when $z=0$ ) sir please help me, please reply.

Answer (score 0):

The derivation given in the other answer is purely formal, as Ahlfors points out:
[image]
(The equation (5) is just $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},$$ which is of course equivalent to the usual CR equations.) Notice how he says "if the rules of calculus *were* applicable"; these manipulations are purely symbolic, and one must *define* $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar{z}}$ by the equation
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar{z}}:=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) .$$
From this is clear that the equation $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar{z}}=0$$ is equivalent to the usual CR equations. One cannot really derive this equation (as it is done in the other answer), because one first has to define $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar{z}}$, **and as Ahlfors says, it has no convenient definition as a limit**. If one forgets about this, it is easy to fool oneself into thinking that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$. But in fact $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ is equal to the complex derivative $f'$ of $f$; this is one reason why this formalism is convenient.